# Push my project into Git hub repository via another php application

Tags: javascript, php, github

I have an `html5/javascript/php` application ready. I want to push my some other projects into `github` repository via my existing application.

So I want to do all create repo (`stage`, `commit`, `push` and `update`) steps  from my existing application.

How can I do that?

Comment: What IDE do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Since you use PHP, PHP can call external commands via [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or [`system`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php), then use these functions to call Git commands with the arguments (e.g repository you need) and fetch the results (if failed for example).

I used something similar to make an Subversion web application for a client.

For example have HTML/JavaScript create an interface where user can set repository parameters and arguments and pass (or post these) to PHP. Then PHP will use `exec` or `system` (with the necessary validation and escaping of course) to call Git commands for the repository and return the results back to PHP then from PHP back to JS app (via AJAX for example).

Further info: if the Git commands need to take some time to complete (have a timeout, or need to communicate with remote repositories and so on), a solution is to use a central data management (i.e a database with only one table pending_processes for example) like this:

Have JS post the Git request to PHP, have PHP add an entry to the `pending_processes` DB table for this current process and set its `status` to `pending`. Have PHP return the `id` of this (Git) process. have same PHP script, use `exec` (or `system`) (fork and) execute the Git command and wait (or poll) for Git command completion. When the Git completes, the same (forked) PHP script, updates the central DB table for this proces to new `status` (e.g `completed` or `failed`, whatever suits your needs and use-cases). Optionaly it can add the result or output of the Git command.

Have JS in the meantime poll (e.g via Ajax calls) the `status` of this command via another PHP script which simply accepts the `id` and checks the central processes table for the `status` of this process. If the `status` is `completed`, it can optionaly fetch the output or result back into the JS app. Then JS will show the result of the command to the user.

Hope this clear and helpful to you. This can be a complex application, needing to synchronise different parts in various levels of the web stack (i.e client/server/php/js/gti and so on). So the trick is to have the general outline and scheme and start simple then progressively build more complex interaction.

Comment: Thank you Nikos. It will be very helpful if you give some example code. Actually I am new in coding.

Comment: @Sneha, this can be a very complex application and code will depend on how you start. The trick is to start simple and implement only the simplest of cases and progresively build more complex use-cases. A sample code is given as the PHP `exec` functions. use just this function to call an external git command (for example `git push`) and see how it works. Then build more complex examples and allow the user (through the HTML app) to add the parameters for git commands

Comment: @Sneha, you will certainly have to update or further your knowledge of PHP, Javascript and Git in order to even start the application. This answer gives the layout (as per your question) and it cannot cover all the ground needed. By implementing the application you will probably come up with further questions and you can post them on stackoverflow as well, since they will be  more specific